# PHP Regex not matching string as expected

Tags: php, regex

The Regex:

```
https?://([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,50}[.])*[a-zA-z0-9-_]{1,50}[.]([(org)(gov)(com)]{3}|[(us)(fi)]{2})
```

The Tester:

```
http://regex.powertoy.org/
```

The Code:

```
if(preg_match_all('|https?://([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,50}[.])*[a-zA-z0-9-_]{1,50}[.]([(org)(gov)(com)]{3}|[(us)(fi)]{2})|',$row['text'],$links))
    {
        print_r($links[0]);
        /*for($x=0;$x<count(links[0]);$x++)
        {
            $row['text'] = str_replace($links[0][$x], 'link' . $link[0][$x] . 'link', $row['text'];
        }*/
    }else{
        echo 'Failure!';
    }
```

The regex matches URLs in the tester fine, but not at all in an HTML/PHP front end.  I'm not sure what the problem is.  The point of the regex/code is basically to match URLs regardless of the number of subdomains.

Comment: What does the code look like and what input is not matching when it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix of your regex pattern is:

```
https?:\/\/(?:[\w-]{1,50}\.)*[\w-]{1,50}\.(?:org|gov|com|us|fi)
```

But I recommend to use:

```
https?:\/\/(?:[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:\-[a-zA-Z\d]+)*\.)+(?:org|gov|com|us|fi)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `|` character as your delimiter but you are also using it in your regex.

I would recommend using another character and making the regex case-insensitive to avoid problems like where you have for example `a-zA-z`:

```
preg_match_all('#https?://([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,50}[.])*[a-zA-z0-9-_]{1,50}[.]([(org)(gov)(com)]{3}|[(us)(fi)]{2})#i',$row['text'],$links)
```

Comment: There should be no underscore allowed in the domain name and dash character cannot be first or last character of (sub-)domain

Comment: @Ωmega To be honest, I didn't really look at the regex itself, but mainly why it would work in the tester but not in php.

Comment: My vote up because you actually explained the problem of the pattern, though you don't need `[a-zA-Z]` if you use `i` pattern modifier

Comment: @dualed True, that was kind of implied with the case-insensitivity. I would probably use `\w` and put the `-` at the beginning or the end to avoid it turning into a range as well.